# ChromeDriver Selenium exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using Mac laptop, I got this from youtube for mac tutorial, but its working for other students

Forgive me I am new to selenium

Not sure if Im missing something[image: Picture of the exception]

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/c054148/Downloads/chromedriver");
    WebDriver obj = new ChromeDriver();
    obj.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

}  **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.(DriverService.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.(ChromeDriverService.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: It seems like you have not added some dependency jars. See if there are any additional files to be included into the project.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have missed the extension of the ChromeDriver. It should be **chromedriver.exe**

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/c054148/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
```